# How to determine the exact coordinates of a Google Street View Image

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, google-street-view

I am currently working on a script which generates random coordinates and gets a Google Street View Image via [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=de)

```
$img_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=[RANDOM_LATITUDE],%20[RANDOM_LONGTITUDE]&sensor=false&key=[API_KEY]';
```

This works perfectly fine, but I want to go a step further:

If the random coordinates don't happen to land directly on a street, but on a building or a park for example, Google Street View Image API returns an image of a location from which the random coordinates are *visible*.

I would like to determine the coordinates of where the **street view car** was standing when it took the picture.

Any help or idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Those are the coordinates of the panorama.  You can get them using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Streetview Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service